# How to solve a polynomial with, multiple solutions, including complex solutions in python?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm trying to solve the following polynomial in python. Some of the constants (2.11 and .125567481) are dynamic and will change in the program. I need a way to calculate the solutions to this equation in python. I tried using Sympy but it was executing forever and never came up with a solution. Wolfram Alpha gives 4 solutions, 3 of them complex, and 1 real. I only need the real one. Is there any way to solve this equation in python efficiently? It's really easy to do in mathematica, but I can't find a way to do it in python3 that is efficient.

(To use it with symPy's fsolve function I had to manipulate the equation so it was equal to zero. It still didn't find the soltuion.)

[image: equation to solve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a polynomial, as d is raised to a fractional degree. An equation that's full of floating point constants is not likely to benefit from a symbolic package like SymPy. A numeric real-valued solution is easy to obtain with SciPy:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from math import pi
fsolve(lambda d: 0.125567481 * (d+0.04) - d**2.25 * (pi*2.11+0.10053 + 2.513274*d), 1)
```

returns `array([ 0.06086999])`

Note that I cleared the denominators (multiplying both sides with them), because division makes the numerical solution harder. Roughly: the more the expression looks like a polynomial the better. And I rearranged the expression so it's equated to 0, as required by the syntax of [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).

The number 1 is a guess for solution; it does not have to be a good one; it just takes a moment of thought: we need a positive root, so let's start with a positive number.

Comment: It can be interpreted as a polynomial if you raise both sides to the power 4, but then you get a degree 9 polynomial which doesn't seem to have any closed form solutions (that SymPy can find anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a polynomial, **it can be rewritten as a polynomial with a simple change of variable** (*see* [scicomp answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/28122/22133)).

[image: equation]

(And, no, this wasn't obvious to me either.)

Regarding the use of sympy: It was easy to substitute `x**4` for `d` in your equation. However, I was unable to make sympy simplify the result to form a polynomial; I had to intervene myself. It appears unable to simplify things like `(x**4)**2.25` or even `(x**Rational(4,1))**Rational(9,4)`. However, once I created the 'right' polynomial (which differs slightly from the answer mentioned above) I was able to solve it.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> solns = solve(-2.51327*x**13 - 6.72929*x**9 + 0.125567*x**4 + 0.00502268)
>>> for soln in solns:
...     complex(soln)**4
... 
(0.06086985138363513+0j)
(-2.6673440204687155-0.010256728791817847j)
(-2.6673440204687155+0.010256728791817847j)
(-0.012167382796929273+0.04441373756373712j)
(-0.012167382796929273-0.04441373756373712j)
(-0.026142016477445254-0.019106863886537373j)
(-0.026142016477445254+0.019106863886537373j)
(0.033815240883517075+0.04622428318735341j)
(0.033815240883517075-0.04622428318735341j)
(-0.025940729836752045-0.005117470121713441j)
(-0.025940729836752045+0.005117470121713441j)
(-2.687663636550892-0.010066278345304842j)
(-2.687663636550892+0.010066278345304842j)
```

Solution was not lightning fast, and it would still be necessary to remove false roots.

As always, it's important to remember that Wolfram-Alpha, written largely in lisp, incorporates a lot of machine intelligence.

Comment: SymPy does not simplify powers unless it knows it is safe to do so. For complex numbers it's only safe with integer exponents. Even for real x, `(x**4)**(9/4)` is not the same as `x**9` (consider negative x). If x is declared real, `x = Symbol('x', real=True)`, then `(x**4)**Rational(9, 4)` correctly returns
`x**8*Abs(x)` instead of `x**9`. If it is declared positive, `x = Symbol('x', positive=True)`, then  `(x**4)**Rational(9, 4)` returns `x**9`.

Comment: @Desire: Excellent response! Thank you. Would you care to respond to my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46914910/131187?