# Deliberately simplifying fractional exponents

Tags: sympy

I have an expression involving fractional exponents that I want to make into a polynomial recognisable to sympy for solution. I could, if necessary, write the exponents using `Rational` but can't make that work.

What can I do?

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('d x')
(d, x)
>>> (0.125567*(d + 0.04) - d**2.25*(2.51327*d + 6.72929)).subs(d,x**4)
0.125567*x**4 - (2.51327*x**4 + 6.72929)*(x**4)**2.25 + 0.00502268
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SymPy does not combine exponents unless it knows it is safe to do so. For complex numbers it's only safe with integer exponents. Since we don't know if x is real or complex, the exponents are not combined.

Even for real x, `(x**4)**(9/4)` is not the same as `x**9` (consider negative x). If `x` is declared real, using `x = Symbol('x', real=True)`, then `(x**4)**Rational(9, 4)` correctly returns `x**8*Abs(x)` instead of `x**9`.

If `x` is declared positive, `x = Symbol('x', positive=True)`, then `(x**4)**Rational(9, 4)` returns `x**9`.

---

It is not advisable to use floating point representation of rational numbers in SymPy, especially as exponents. This is why I replaced 2.25 by `Rational(9, 4)` above. With 2.25, the result is `Abs(x)**9.0` when x is real, and `x**9.0` if x is declared positive. The decimal dot indicates these are floating point numbers; so subsequent manipulations will have floating-point results instead of symbolic ones. For example (with x declared positive):

```
>>> solve((x**4)**Rational(9, 4) - 2)
[2**(1/9)]
>>> solve((x**4)**2.25 - 2)
[1.08005973889231]
```